# Get Firestore subcollections without use id

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore

I have a problem with getting data from the Firestore with a following structure

[image]

Here is how I get category collection:

```
app.get('/getProjectsNo', (request, response) => {
  response.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')

  let orders = []

  db.collection('companies').doc('renaultsomaca').collection('orders').get().then(snapshot => {
    snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      orders.push(doc.data())
    });
    response.send(orders)
  })
})
```

It gives me: orders list.But I need to get orders without using doc('renaultsomaca').Because I just need all orders not only renaultsomaca orders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're describing is known as a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query), which queries across all collections with a specific name.

To get all documents from `orders` collections, no matter where they are in the database, you'd do:

```
const querySnapshot = await db.collectionGroup('orders').get();
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
  console.log(doc.id, ' => ', doc.data());
});
```

There is no way to specify the path to the `orders` collection, so if you have multiple types of orders that you want to query separately, you'll have to give them distinct names.